# Could you explain why variable has different value when declare variable inside of function?

Tags: algorithm, go

At the first time, I write code like this. but variable `left` always has value `-1`.

```golang
func diameterOfBinaryTree(root *TreeNode) int {
    var longest int
    var left int
    var right int
    max := func(a, b int) int {
        if a > b {
            return a
        }
        return b
    }
    var dfs func(*TreeNode) int
    dfs = func(node *TreeNode) int {
        if node == nil {
            return -1
        }
        left = dfs(node.Left)
        right = dfs(node.Right)

        longest = max(longest, left+right+2)
        return (max(left, right) + 1)
    }
    dfs(root)
    return longest
}
```

and after change code like this, left has right value.

```golang
func diameterOfBinaryTree(root *TreeNode) int {
    var longest int
    max := func(a, b int) int {
        if a > b {
            return a
        }
        return b
    }
    var dfs func(*TreeNode) int
    dfs = func(node *TreeNode) int {
        if node == nil {
            return -1
        }
        left := dfs(node.Left)
        right := dfs(node.Right)

        longest = max(longest, left+right+2)
        return (max(left, right) + 1)
    }
    dfs(root)
    return longest
}
```

what is difference ?? please let me know.

I think variable `left` should have different value after recursion but not.

Comment: The first code uses a function closure while the second uses proper local variables. Take the Tour of Go to learn about variables and closures. Short: dfs(node.Right) clobbers the left in the first example.

Comment: As you said, It's hard to understand because of dfs(node.Right). thx! @Volker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the `left` variable is in the closure of the inner lambda. That means that this variable is "global" from the point of view of the function. As the lambda is recursive, each call crushes the previous value, at the end (of the recursion) its value is -1 (the recursion base case) and never changed after (when going back from the recursion).

In the second case, `left` is a local variable and then pushed/popped to/from the stack at each call.